# Need to click download button that matches the given text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to download the Invoice that has Tax Invoice written in the table for which I iterate over the table element and fetch the required details. But when I click on the Download button it downloads the same invoice twice. How do I make it download the second "Tax Invoice"? Below is the image:

[image]

and the html code:

[image]

and below is the code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC




driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:/Chrome driver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("the link")

time.sleep(10)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="GST"]/div/div/a[2]/span[1]'))).click()

driver.switch_to.frame('ifgstdownloadnFrame')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtpnr"]').send_keys('QYJ27J')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnSubmit"]').click()

mytable = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table.gstInvoiceGrid")

for row in mytable.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
    for cell in row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td'):
        if 'Tax Invoice' in cell.text:
            print()
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.download.downloadbutton').click()
time.sleep(10)
            
#driver.quit()
```

Comment: this line: driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.download.downloadbutton').click()  Isn't relative to the row you're on.   I would try a selector that targets the id, or invoice.  This makes the code much simpler.  No need to find the table or the rows/cells.

Comment: The table keeps changing sometimes it will have four entries, sometimes six or even 2 so I was matching the text and since the entries in the table won't be fixed the id will keep chnaging.

Comment: //td[text()='Tax Invoice']/../td:last-child/input  Should find all the input tags to click

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was using driver instead of using row then that's why it was downloading the first Tax Invoice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Change the logic to find `intermediate` cell by using `dot` use either of the following code logic which will click each download button having `Tax Invoice`.

```
for row in mytable.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
    for cell in row.find_elements_by_xpath('./td'):
        if 'Tax Invoice' in cell.text:
            print()
            row.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@value='Download']").click()
```

Or

```
for row in mytable.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
    if row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[text()='Tax Invoice']"):
        row.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@value='Download']").click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Works Fine with 'row.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@value='Download']").click() '.